# How can I dynamically replace portions of text with TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, dynamic-controls

#### TL;DR:

I need to insert a TextBox into a PlaceHolder wherever I see a token like `@token@`, and splitting on `@` won't cut it. How can I do this?

#### Setup:

I have a database-driven ASP.NET page with merge fields in several places. On one of the admin pages, I want to make the text in the merge fields editable by showing TextBoxes where the merge fields are. The rest of the text needs to stay non-editable.

The input looks like this:

> "the quick brown fox **@foo@** jumps over **@bar@** the lazy **@baz@** dog."

The merge fields here would be `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`. I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the value of the merge fields:

```
var Tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "foo", "john" },
    { "bar", "george" },
    //...etc...
};
```

#### Goal:

For each of these text blocks, I have a PlaceHolder. What I'd like to do is dynamically insert a Label for each block of uneditable text, and a TextBox for each editable block. So the results of the above would be as if I had hard-coded something like this:

```
<asp:Label   Text="the quick brown fox" />
<asp:TextBox ID="foo" Text="john" />
<asp:Label   Text="jumps over" />
<asp:TextBox ID="bar" Text="george" />
<asp:Label   Text="the lazy" />
...etc...
```

#### Problem:

Matching the `@token@` pattern is easy. The trick is adding the Labels and TextBoxes in the right places. There might be more than one token in a given input, so I have to separate it out into editable and non-editable text, **while still keeping track of which merge variable each TextBox corresponds to.** As it turns out, this is not as easy as it sounds. I could use regular expressions to convert the input string into HTML, replacing the `@token@` pattern with `<input>` tags. However, that has a couple of problems:

- I already have a ton of code for the dynamic-server-controls approach.
- I only want to match specific tokens, so `/@[a-zA-Z\d]+@/` isn't strict enough.

#### Previous Strategy:

Until now, I simply split the input string on `@`, then inserted a Label for each odd-numbered substring and a TextBox for each even substring. That worked fine, but the requirements are changing. `@` symbols will now be allowed outside of a variable name, so the input string might look like:

> blah blah@blah.com **@foo@** blah

...in which case only `foo` would be a merge field.

#### Current Strategy:

I feel like I need to iterate through Tokens and build some sort of array of Labels and TextBoxes. The problem is that any number of tokens might be in the input, so once I split out TextBoxes for `@foo@`, I need to go through the text *again* for instances of `@bar@`. I think I need some sort of recursion for this, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before **fantasticfix**'s answer was posted, I started working on a recursive method using string manipulation. It seems to be working correctly, so I'm posting it here for anyone else:

```
private void tokenize(PlaceHolder ph, string str)
{
    int index = str.IndexOf('@') + 1;

    if (index == 0)
    {
        ph.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = str });
        return;
    }

    ph.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = str.Substring(0, index - 1) });

    if (Tokens.Keys.Any(k => str.Substring(index).StartsWith(k + "@")))
    {
        int next = str.IndexOf("@", index);
        string key = str.Substring(index, next - index);

        ph.Controls.Add(new TextBox
        {
            ID = "txt" + key,
            Text = Tokens[key],
            TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine,
            Rows = 2
        });

        index = next + 1;
    }

    tokenize(ph, str.Substring(index));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with Regular expressions.
The Expression would look something like:

```
@([a-zA-Z0-9])+@
```

this would mean that it matches for all patterns which start with @, contain at least one character a-z or A-Z or 0-9 and end with @

[Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx)

Comment: +1, also you can check if the matched name actually exist as a variable and if not treat it like normal text.

Comment: The issue isn't matching the patterns. That's not too hard. The issue is dynamically adding the Labels and TextBoxes, and figuring out which Label/TextBox goes where.

Comment: so then you loop through the matches with the code snippet from the link and replace the found matches with the Text. the return value of match is "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match", which contains Index (where it starts) Lenght(the length of the match wohoo) and value (the found substring). with these values it should be a piece of cake to replace it.

Comment: your problem before was that you could not identify single @. (at least that was what you stated as problem) with the regex solution you solve exactly this problem

Comment: That wasn't the entire problem; it was more like a small change that screwed up the previous solution. I'm thinking this idea over, though...I might be able to make it work. However, it won't be able to handle inputs like `blah blah@blah@foo@ blah`, where `@foo@` is the only variable.

Comment: thats possible to handle cause you have the dictionary with the variablenames you want to match. you can check on each match if the value exists in in the dictionary. "blah blah@blah@foo@ blah" matches on @blah@ AND @foo@. thats the huge advantage of regex compared to splitting the string

Comment: I think you're right--that could work. I'm going to accept my answer below because that's the one I used, but you have an upvote from me. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: BTW, one little FYI - your pattern wouldn't match `@blah@` and `@foo@` from `blah blah@blah@foo@ blah` because they overlap. .NET regex doesn't accept overlapping matches. `@([a-zA-Z0-9])+(?=@)`, however, would match `@blah` and `@foo`.